# I co-own a house with my Mom. Should I move it under my name 100%?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, home-ownership

I purchased a house as a non-occupant buyer with Mom a year ago.  It is her home.  Good decision at the time for a few reasons and I put down the full down payment (20%).  I am thinking that long term that it would be best if the house is fully under my name to reduce liability for both of us (she is 70+).  I have the extra funds to pay it off and could get a 2nd mortgage later if needed.

Two questions:

1. Would you agree with my assessment that it would be best if the house is only in my name to reduce liability?  Her monthly payment will be lower and we would both still make money once it is sold.
2. How do we go about transferring to my name 100% after I pay off the mortgage with no tax implications?  Do we go to the county and transfer ownership?

thank you

Comment: I think that last part is where you will get fouled up.  To my knowledge you can't just transfer a house from one person to another with no tax implications at all.  Others here may be able to answer in more detail with regards to that, but I'd say you should consult a professional before you do anything.  It may very well be best if she leaves the house (or proceeds) to you as part of her estate; or gifts you money each year from the proceeds if you chose to sell.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response Keith.  I was thinking that once the mortgage is paid off, and the mortgage company submits a release to the county, a quitclaim will do.

Comment: Of course, if your name is already on the deed, that may help.  I couldn't really tell from your post if that was the case or not.

Comment: Have you talked to your lender about a streamline to remove your mother from the mortgage? I know that's a method to remove a non-occupant buyer from a mortgage, might also be used to remove the occupant buyer. Also, how would you both make money when you sold if it's only in your name?

Comment: Please specify the country: legal and tax questions require it.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Isn't the convention to only tag a country if the question isn't about the US?

Comment: this is in the US.  I handled the down payment and all the closing costs so I am not sure there would be a transfer of value.  Perhaps a slight amount of estimated equity as it is worth more but that is less than $10K.

Comment: I  appreciate all the comments on question #2 (transferring to my name),  Does anyone have an answer to #1 - does it makes sense to transfer 100% to my name given I have the funds to pay if off?  An advantage of keeping it in both our names is we can keep the current 1st mortgage with a low interest rate and I would not tie up extra funds paying off the house.  My concern is if something happened to her resulting in debt (medical bills), the house would be an asset of hers.  A legitimate concern?

Comment: @HartCO  [No](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/72/25282), there is no such convention.  All questions should have country tags except for a very small set of exceptions (e.g. definitions of international terminology).

Comment: What would happen if you happened to die before her?  Would the house, now owned 100% by you, go to your heirs who might not have any incentive to let her keep living there, or sell if she needs to pay for e.g. long-term care?

Comment: @Keith -- if a gift is more than the $14,000 annual exclusion, the amount that exceeds $14,000 counts against the $5.45 million lifetime exclusion. You don't owe any taxes until you use up that lifetime exclusion.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure that is correct, unless it is specific to property transferred between family members.  Can you cite a source on that?  Thx

Comment: @Keith -- just google "lifetime exemption". [Here](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Tax-Planning-and-Checklists/The-Gift-Tax-Made-Simple/INF12127.html) is one of the first hits I got.

Comment: @PeteBecker So basically you just have to file the paperwork with the IRS, but it just comes out of your estate tax limit.  OK, I did not know that.

Answer (score 3):

If it's in your name and you don't live there, there's a number of issues. If you charge her rent, it needs to be at fair value to treat it as a rental property.

If she lives there for the next 20 years, it will (or we hope) gain value. If she passes while it's in her name you get to step up the basis, and avoid tax. If in your name , the gain would be taxable.

Answer (score 1):

Sit down with professional with knowledge about eldercare issues. Know how your options regarding the property ownership can impact the services they qualify for. Even making a change in ownership can impact their eligibility for certain programs. Some of which can reach back to events in the recent past. Also if you own it but she will get some of the profits when you sell, she could still be considered an owner, which can impact eligibility for programs.

This is in addition to the issues with the lender, the IRS, and your estate.